# Delete downloaded remote file with WinSCP script

Tags: powershell, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I have a PowerShell script that is working great to grab some files from a remote SFTP.  But I can not get the code to delete the files after download.  Here is what I have.

```
$session.Open($sessionOptions)

# Set up transfer options
$transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions -Property @{
    ResumeSupport = New-Object WinSCP.TransferResumeSupport -Property @{ State = [WinSCP.TransferResumeSupportState]::Off }
}

# Transfer files
$session.GetFiles("/remote/*.txt", "\\Local\*", $False, $transferOptions).Check()

# Delete Transfers
$session.RemoveFiles($difference.Remote.FileName)
```

Instead I get an error that states:

```
Removals Failures                                                                                                                                                    
-------- --------                                                                                                                                                    ---------
{}       {WinSCP.SessionRemoteException: Error listing directory '"/Files'....                                                                                           False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete the downloaded files from the server, just pass `true` to the `remove` (3rd) argument of  [`Session.GetFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles):

```
$session.GetFiles("/remote/*.txt", "C:\local\*", $True, $transferOptions).Check()
```